# How do I model this item?

Tags: modeling

I am able to model in blender. I am also not a noob. But for the love of God I can't seem to figure out how to model this toggle-switch in blender. How to begin and how to model faithfully. If you can then please guide me. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What did you try and where did you fail?

Comment: First i tried to use empty vertex to chalk out the 2d shape. Then i tried primitives. Then boolean. But none is satisfactory. I think i am having a mental block or something.

Comment: Is it the red part you're having trouble with?  Do you have a poly limit?  Do you want "good" all-quads topology?

Comment: Yes, the red part. And i can't be high poly. And a good topo is also required. (I wished to model it from a single cube but unable to do so.)

Comment: No One got any answers??

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: If my answer below didn't answer your question then some more detail could be helpful, such as end use (modeling for games has important differences from doing it for animation, for example), how closely this will be seen, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think starting with something roughly like this:

[image]

[image]

Some loops can be removed or added depending on how much detail/support is needed.  If a hole for the axle isn't needed then topology like the other protrusions can be used there.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you! That's just so kind of you!

Comment: Happy it helped!

Comment: Although I have been doing 2D art all my life and shifted to 3D in the recent past, I feel the 3D community is far more supportive than any other art group. :D

Comment: I would like to ask one question. How did you shape the right hand side curve in the 2D image?

Comment: I made a 128-sided cylinder with a triangle-fan cap (some people would use a circle, I find the faces of the cap easier to work with).  I deleted everything but I think nine faces of the cap, the outer rim of which became the right hand side curve in the 2D image.  Subdivided the inside edges once, and deleted the remaining trigons, the inner curve became the left hand side curve in the 2D image -- they both got a lot of loopcutting, deleting, scaling, and rotating after that, but that's how I started them.

Comment: Thank you for explaining and being so generous.

Comment: You're welcome -- just try to remember next time that a lot of Blender questions may be best answered with images, vids, and/or .blend files, and these can take time to prepare.  It took a couple hours to get the example in my answer done around the other stuff I was doing when I saw your question, I wasn't sure if it would turn out potentially helpful, and an hour in you commented wondering why we hadn't answered yet.  Some more patience, please!

Comment: Sure mate! Cheers!